# replace all links in webpage with new link

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I need to replace all links in this style with new link. I am fasting the download process of google drive link.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cCIWJMBOX-NvzYVTQajaVo5lNknYA2E8/view?usp=sharing

my idea is to get '1cCIWJMBOX-NvzYVTQajaVo5lNknYA2E8' from link and make new link which is direct download link.

for that I wrote regex

```
new RegExp('https://drive.google.com/file/d/' + "(.*)" + '/view')
```

it works well.

but I do not understand how to make duplicate link which is direct downloadable.

```js
new RegExp('https://drive.google.com/file/d/' + "(.*)" + '/view');
```

```html
<a href="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cCIWJMBOX-NvzYVTQajaVo5lNknYA2E8/view?usp=sharing">https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cCIWJMBOX-NvzYVTQajaVo5lNknYA2E8/view?usp=sharing</a>
```

what i need as result is both links I write below. so I can click on any desired link and download files.
these links are in my website pages so I have to search in document for regex matching and replace links to get below results

`<a href="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cCIWJMBOX-NvzYVTQajaVo5lNknYA2E8/view?usp=sharing">https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cCIWJMBOX-NvzYVTQajaVo5lNknYA2E8/view?usp=sharing</a>`

```
<a href="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=NvzYVTQajaVo5lNknYA2E8&export=download">direct download</a>
```

Comment: If you want help you may have to rewrite this question because it makes little to no sense.  `I am fasting the download process`, did you mean `speeding up` the process?  Your question starts off as if you need to learn how to use `RegExp` to extract part of a `URL` but devolves into what appears to be a request for converting between different types of Google Drive links, but without a clear, focused question you are unlikely to get useful answers.

Comment: By the way, `(?<=https:\/\/drive.google.com\/file\/d\/).*(?=\/view)` is the proper `RegExp` for matching what you did in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or, in a shorter version, the following will get you the same:

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="drive.google.com"]')].forEach(a=>a.outerHTML+=`
  <br><a href="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=${a.href.match(/file\/d\/(.*)\/view/)[1]}&export=download">direct download</a>`)
```

```html
<div>link 1 <br>
  <a href="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cCIWJMBOX-NvzYVTQajaVo5lNknYA2E8/view?usp=sharing">https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cCIWJMBOX-NvzYVTQajaVo5lNknYA2E8/view?usp=sharing</a>
  <br>
</div>
<br>
<div>My baby yoda pic link 2 test<br>
  <a href="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sRXR9-UgiXP-vKyTznrK8L_07zQaNAuq/view?usp=sharing">https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sRXR9-UgiXP-vKyTznrK8L_07zQaNAuq/view?usp=sharing</a>
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice and short, just a slight mistake: it goes `&export=download` , not `?export=download`. Links where not working...

Comment: Hi @ikiK, thanks for pointing it out! Silly mistake, just fixed it.

Comment: Check my modified answer again: The selector is now a bit more selective and will only process links with "drive.google.com" in the `href` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you need something like this?

```js
const links = document.querySelectorAll("a");

for (const link of links) {
if (link.href.indexOf("drive.google.com")>-1){
  var href = link.href;
  var li = href.split("/");
  //li[5] = li[5].split("-")[1];
  //console.log(li[5]);

  var createA = document.createElement('a');
  var newline = document.createElement('br');
  var createAText = document.createTextNode("direct download");
  createA.setAttribute('href', "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=" + li[5] + "&export=download");
  link.appendChild(newline);
  createA.appendChild(createAText);
  link.appendChild(createA);
}
}

const links2 = document.querySelectorAll("a");
for (const link2 of links2) {
  if (link2.href.indexOf("download") >= 0) {
    console.log(link2.href);
  }
}
```

```html
<div>link 1 <br>
  <a href="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cCIWJMBOX-NvzYVTQajaVo5lNknYA2E8/view?usp=sharing">https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cCIWJMBOX-NvzYVTQajaVo5lNknYA2E8/view?usp=sharing</a>
  <br>
</div>
<br>
<div>My baby yoda pic link 2 test<br>
  <a href="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sRXR9-UgiXP-vKyTznrK8L_07zQaNAuq/view?usp=sharing">https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sRXR9-UgiXP-vKyTznrK8L_07zQaNAuq/view?usp=sharing</a>
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: hi but one issue there. this script replace all the links in page, but I really want to replace google drive links only. that is why i started with regex. how to make this to work only with google drive links? –

Comment: @user291830 that was easy, just modify the CSS selector to be more precise. I see other answer corrected it before me anyway. or you could use if statement with indexOf

Comment: @user291830 I added if statement: `if (link.href.indexOf("drive.google.com")>-1){` put what ever you want inside to react to it. Or you could use match...

Answer (score 0):

above two answers are helpful. I modified answers and came up with this.

```js
const links = document.querySelectorAll("a");

for (const link of links) {
  var href = link.href;
  var li = href.split("/");
  var y = href.match(new RegExp('https://drive.google.com/file/d/' + "(.*)" + '/view'));
  
  var href2;
  if(y){
      href2='https://drive.google.com/uc?id=' +y[1]+'&export=download';
      console.log(href2);
      var createA = document.createElement('a');
      var newline = document.createElement('br');
      var createAText = document.createTextNode("direct download");
      createA.setAttribute('href', href2);
      link.appendChild(newline);
      createA.appendChild(createAText);
      link.appendChild(createA);
  }
}

const links2 = document.querySelectorAll("a");
for (const link2 of links2) {
  if (link2.href.indexOf("download") >= 0) {
    //console.log(link2.href);
  }
}
```